# typedef _W64 unsigned int UINT_PTR, *PUINT_PTR;

Tags: c++

What does exactly this mean?

```
typedef _W64 unsigned int UINT_PTR, *PUINT_PTR;
```

Does this mean that *PUINT_PTR is a pointer (obviously) and UINT_PTR is NOT a pointer? If so, why is it called UINT_PTR ? (which I would read as unsigned int pointer, or pointer to unsigned int)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this means that `PUINT_PTR` is a pointer and `UINT_PTR` is not a pointer.  It's a little confusing, but a `UINT_PTR` (as well as the more standardized `uintptr_t`) is defined to be an unsigned integer that is guaranteed to be large enough to hold a pointer value.  It's typically used for tricky code where pointers are put into integer values and vice-versa.

The `_W64` annotation is a note to the Miscrosoft compiler that when compiling for a 64-bit target, the variable should be 64 bits wide instead of the usual 32, since on 64-bit platforms, pointers are 64 bits, but `unsigned int`s are usually still 32 bits.  This ensures that `sizeof(UINT_PTR) >= sizeof(void*)` for all target platforms.

The second declaration just declares `PUINT_PTR` to be a pointer to a `_W64 unsigned int`, or more specifically, a pointer to a `UINT_PTR`.